# my span is floating behind - I need it on top

Tags: html, css, hover, z-index

I've tried this from so many angles but can't figure it out.

See my map here: http://defendiendovidas.org/test.html

I need the country names in  to appear on top of everything else. z-index isn't helping, even though my span is position:absolute.

Any pointers to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. if anyone has a suggestion for how to build this map better, I'd be keen to hear. Thing is, I want the fade-on-hover effect. But my images are overlapping and therefore as you can see with Brazil, the hover is kind of conflicting with nearby countries (images) that are positioned "on top" of Brazil. map/area is no good because it doesn't allow for area:hover...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code please? Cool looking map btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to apply the opacity to the `img` and not to the entire `li`,

since `opacity` and `z-index` are somehow connected.

Also, since you've asked if anyone has a suggestion how to make this map better, well...

Your code was really messy and you've also used `li`s outside of a list for some reason, so I kind of changed a lot of the HTML too.

Here's the Fiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/JTa6g/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful. You sure did clean that code up a lot!

Of course - that makes sense now you explained it! the `span` was inside the `li`, thus it was getting faded.

I am interested though - if you have any idea on how to solve the issue of the overlapping images conflicting with the "clickability" of nearby images. In particular, Brazil - if you mouseover the left side of Brazil you see that the `hover` does not work.

I think it works well enough for now, but I do wish I could find a fix for this annoying aspect of the map.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to see a full map here. You have mentioned it too. Well there is also no other span found! 
The map is somehow cool. But if you want the images to ride over the image. You might use the position relative!
Have you tried that? You have an absolute, but absolute works on the div or container its relative too. If there is no container having position relative the main body tag is considered to be the one. So try giving this image a relative position. Then add the z-index and absolute position!

Answer (score -1):

Try `Position:relative` or `Position:absolute`
Give z-index a  shot too, `z-index:50`